# AWS ELB + ejabberd server

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, xmpp, ejabberd

I have two servers in AWS EC2 ejabberd. I'm trying to set up an ELB to manage traffic, but I can not connect when I put a ELB "front" of EC2 instances. DNS settings, I changed the A record for the CNAME public DNS name of the instance ELB.

I read that SRV records can not point to a CNAME, so is not it possible to use ELB + ejabberd?

regards

Answer (score 1):

> so is not it possible to use ELB + ejabberd?

It is possible.

XMPP should work via ELB as long as the ELB is configured with a TCP listener instead of HTTP.

You can put the preferred subdomain, a CNAME of the ELB, as the SRV records and that shouldn't be a problem.

This post covers setting up ejabberd behind an ELB: http://overwatering.org/blog/2014/03/straight-forward-clustering-of-ejabberd/